# reading zTee subject files in R

Tags: r, encoding, import, ztree

I want to import zTree subjects data files (quetionaire) to R and I am using [zTreeSbj function written by Oliver Kirchkamp](http://www.kirchkamp.de/lab/zTree.R):

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "*.sbj$",recursive=TRUE)
fname <- sub(".*/","",files)
sbj <- zTreeSbj(aggregate(files,list(fname),function(x) x[1])$x)
```

I get the following error:

```
reading  1 ...
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = getOption("zTree.encoding")) : 
invalid 'description' argument
Called from: file(filename, "r", encoding = getOption("zTree.encoding"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, and Oliver Kirchkamp replied to me:

> In your case you do not need aggregate. Simply say:
>
> ```
> files <- list.files(pattern = "*.sbj$",recursive=TRUE)
> sbj <- zTreeSbj(files)
> ```

That worked for me, because I did not have multiple versions of the same .sbj file.